# Installation problem with 18.04LTS

Tags: boot, reboot

Installation seems to go ok until reboot.
Then the screen displays '.04 LTS filer tty1'without a shell prompt.
All the alternate windows (e.g. ctrl+F2) show the same except the tty name changes.

Do I need to enable some option during install to enable an interactive console?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu server or desktop? I'll assume server, since you're talking about `tty` as if you expect to interact on the command line.

Have you tried just typing your username in? It's been my experience on some installs that the prompt is sometimes issued too early and disappears, but it still accepts input. Once you enter your username (you should see it appear on the screen as you type), it should prompt you for a password.